# symmetric ds file sync not working

Tags: symmetricds

Steps followed:

1. I have used below sym configuration at server node , same got reflected in target node also when executed at server.
2. At server I have created at text file at path "source_base_dir" and same file at client at path "target_dir".
3. Modified source file at master, but no triggers and update happening at target path.
   node_id_client is client node id
   source_node_group_id,target_node_group_id is 'server' and 'client' id's
4. Using symmetric ds version 3.8.28

.

```
INSERT INTO sym_file_trigger
          (trigger_id,base_dir,recurse,includes_files,excludes_files,sync_on_create,
          sync_on_modified,sync_on_delete,before_copy_script,after_copy_script,create_time,


last_update_by,last_update_time)
VALUES
  ('node_id_client','source_base_dir',1,null,null,1,1,1,'',null,
  current_timestamp,'example',current_timestamp);

INSERT INTO sym_file_trigger_router
  (trigger_id,router_id,enabled,initial_load_enabled,target_base_dir,
  conflict_strategy,create_time,last_update_by,last_update_time)
VALUES
  ('node_id_client','router_files_to_node',1,1,'target_dir','SOURCE_WINS',
  current_timestamp,'example',current_timestamp);

INSERT INTO sym_router
  (router_id,target_catalog_name,target_schema_name,target_table_name,
   source_node_group_id,target_node_group_id,router_type,router_expression,
   sync_on_update,sync_on_insert,sync_on_delete,create_time,last_update_by,
   last_update_time)
VALUES
  ('router_files_to_node',null,null,null,'server','client','column',
  'RELATIVE_DIR = :NODE_ID ',1,1,1,current_timestamp,'example', current_timestamp);
```

Comment: Any exceptions in the log file?